# Showing that the global formula for the exterior derivative is $C^{\infty}$-linear with respect to $X_i$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For context, I'm trying to make sense of Exercise 1.123 from Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine's Riemannian Geometry book.

I'm assuming (and have proved this is the past usign Tu's book) that for $\alpha\in \Omega^{p}(M)$ and $(X_0, \ldots, X_p)$ are $p+1$ vector fields on $M$, then $$d\alpha(X_0, \ldots, X_p)=\sum_{i=0}^{p}(-1)^{i}L_{X_i}(\alpha(X_0, \ldots, \hat{X_i}, \ldots, X_p))+\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq p}(-1)^{i+j}\alpha([X_i, X_j], X_o, \ldots \hat{X_i}, \ldots, \hat{X_j}, \ldots, X_p),$$ where the hat denotes an omitted term.

I want to show that the right hand side is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear with respect to $X_i$.

This is my setup so far and I'm not sure that it's right either.

$$d\alpha(X_0, \ldots,fX_i, \ldots, X_p)=\sum_{i=0}^{p}(-1)^{i}L_{fX_i}(\alpha(X_0, \ldots, \hat{fX_i}, \ldots, X_p))+\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq p}(-1)^{i+j}\alpha([fX_i, X_j], X_o, \ldots \hat{fX_i}, \ldots, \hat{X_j}, \ldots, X_p),$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{p}(-1)^{i}fL_{X_i}(\alpha(X_0, \ldots, \hat{fX_i}, \ldots, X_p))+
(df\wedge i_{X_i}\alpha)(\alpha(X_0, \ldots, \hat{fX_i}, \ldots, X_p))+
\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq p}(-1)^{i+j}\alpha(fX_i X_j-X_j fX_i, X_o, \ldots \hat{fX_i}, \ldots, \hat{X_j}, \ldots, X_p).$$

How can I finish this or is my setup even correct?

Comment: Why are you even writing the Lie derivative? This is a vector field acting on a function, so $L_X g = Xg$. Your title should say exterior derivative, not Lie derivative. Have you tried writing this out explicitly for a $1$-form $\alpha$, to avoid all the horrendous notation? What about a $2$-form?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I'm sorry for the confusion. I wrote Lie derivative since that's what is was called in Tu's book.

Comment: What what was called? Anyhow, have you done the $1$- and $2$-form cases? You should rarely jump immediately to the general case without first seeing exactly how it’s working in notationally simpler cases.